# ssh bash script No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to run a script from /var/www/backups/scripts and when i try tell it to zip up a file i get the below error,

I can confirm that /var/www is the home dir and that the scripts work when ran manually though putty but just not though a script.

I'm using the below code to run the zip

```
#!/bin/bash
unset PATH

#USER VARS

HOMEDIR=~/
BACKUP_TARG_DIR=~/sites/backups/auto
BACKUP_TEMP_NAME=tempBackupFile.tar
BACKUP_TARG_FILE=/var/www/back
DATE=`/bin/date '+%Y-%m-%d'`


echo  `/bin/pwd`;

tar -zcvf test.rar /var/www/backups/scripts/tryThis

#cd /var/www
#scp "tempBackupFile.tar" 217.41.51.14:~/testfile.rar;
#tar -zcvf $BACKUP_TEMP_NAME $BACKUP_TARG_FILE;
echo "SITE-"$DATE;
```

below is the output i get

```
/var/www/backups/scripts
./autoBackup.bash: line 18: tar: No such file or directory
SITE-2011-09-05
```

Any one have any ideas as this is killing me, all I can think of is its something to do with where the bash script is being run from.

Comment: Are you running the backup script as the same user when invoking from putty or from another script?

Comment: Seems like `tar` is not installed?

Answer (score 10):

Why do you `unset PATH` ?? No wonder bash cannot execute `tar`.

Comment: If you unset PATH, you should use the whole complete path to `tar` when you want to call it.

Comment: I copied it from a tutorial, this is my first time doing this. I got it working using `/bin/tar`, but yes, you are correct; removing the unset PATH has worked. Spent hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure that you don't have a `chroot` directory set.  If you do, you will need to either create a bin directory in the `chroot` directory and either copy or link the necessary binaries into that directory.

Or you could always comment that line out in the config.

Either way, restart sshd and test.